# get instantiated type variable in java

Tags: java, generics, types

I would like to check if the instantiated type of a generic class has certain properties, e.g.:

```
class Foo<T> {
  void bar () { 
    if (T instanceof Serializable)   // does not compile
      ...
  } 
}
```

I am wondering if the generic information is totally lost during runtime? And does that mean there is no way to accomplish what I would like to do?

Comment: "I am wondering if the generic information is totally lost during runtime?" -- yup, exactly

Comment: Even if type-parameters *weren't* erased at runtime, your code still wouldn't compile, since the left-hand argument of `instanceof` must be a *reference*, not a *type*. For example, you can't write `String instanceof Object`.

Comment: `Serializable` isn't something you'd want to assert on an interface type even statically. It's a property of implementation types, and therefore instances.

Comment: You can actually do this using reflection. While ruakh's answer below isn't wrong and represents the "classic" way of doing it, I recommend reading http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html and also http://www.jquantlib.org/index.php/Using_TypeTokens_to_retrieve_generic_parameters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> And does that mean there is no way to accomplish what I would like to do?

You can write:

```
class Foo<T> {
  private final Class<T> clazz;

  Foo (final Class<T> clazz) { // require creator to supply a Class<T>
    this.clazz = clazz;
    if (clazz == null) {
      throw new NullPointerException();
    }
  }

  void bar () { 
    if (Serializable.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
      ...
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: The compiler should do this behind the scenes :-(

Comment: @JanDvorak: Indeed, the decision *not* to do this behind-the-scenes is, according to the *Java Language Specification*, "one of the most [...] controversial design decisions involving the type system of the Java programming language." [Section 4.7 "Reifiable Types"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.7) explains why they did it anyway. In short, it's because they wanted it to be possible for new code to continue to work with pre-compiled old code.

Comment: Nice reading, but I still can't see any incompatibility introduced by allowing `instanceof T`

Comment: I agree with Jan. I think JLS should allow instanceof T in the language.

Comment: @JanDvorak: What's not to see? A pre-Java-5 `List` *forbids* clients from providing any behind-the-scenes `Class<T>` magic (because that didn't exist yet), so if a post-Java-5 `List<T>` *required* that magic (in order to support `T.class`, `instanceof T`, etc.), then there would be a fundamental incompatibility. It would be impossible to compile code that worked with both `List`s, because one would require what the other forbade.

Comment: So the issue is binary compatibility, not source-code compatibility?

Comment: @JanDvorak: Yes. The comment in the JLS actually goes a bit further, essaying a three-way distinction between "language compatibility" (meaning roughly "source-code compatibility"), "platform compatibility" (meaning roughly "binary compatibility for code that doesn't start using the new feature"), and "migration compatibility" (meaning roughly "binary compatibility even for code that does start using the new feature").

Answer (score 2):

You are right, `generic type information` is lost at run-time. It's called [**Type Erasure**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).Compiler would remove all the generic type and do the cast's(if necessary) at run time. and all the